# Excel remove after specific character while ignoring the first 4 instances of that character

Tags: excel

I have a table that is formatted like so:

New York -> ALBANY -> Legal & Financial -> Legal -> ATTORNEYS

where -> is sub category.

i want to limit the entire table to 5 sub-directories.. thus count 5-> then remove everything after that.

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess best is to do a small user defined function in VBA to look for the nth occurence of the seperator string and keeps all that is left of that; example

```
Function CutAt(Arg As String, Sep As String, Level As Integer)
Dim Idx As Integer, ArgLen As Integer, SepLen As Integer, FCnt As Integer

    ArgLen = Len(Arg)                  ' argument length
    SepLen = Len(Sep)                  ' seperator length
                                       ' no check that arglen > seplen !!!
    Idx = 1                            ' position mark
    FCnt = 0                           ' find counter

    For Idx = 1 To ArgLen - SepLen + 1
        If Mid(Arg, Idx, SepLen) = Sep Then FCnt = FCnt + 1
        If FCnt = Level Then Exit For
    Next Idx

    If FCnt = Level Then
        CutAt = Left(Arg, Idx - 1)
    Else
        CutAt = Arg
    End If

End Function
```

Use this as a rather unprotected and unsafe peace of code just to demonstrate the principles - it's maybe not "enduser safe" in each & every way. I tested with

```
A1: New York -> ALBANY -> Legal & Financial -> Legal -> ATTORNEYS -> more -> even more -> much more
A2: New York -> ALBANY -> Legal & Financial -> Legal -> ATTORNEYS -> more -> even more
A3: New York -> ALBANY -> Legal & Financial -> Legal -> ATTORNEYS -> more
A4: New York -> ALBANY -> Legal & Financial -> Legal -> ATTORNEYS
A5: New York -> ALBANY -> Legal & Financial -> Legal
A6: New York -> ALBANY -> Legal & Financial
```

with formula `=cutat(A1,"->",5)` (copied down 6 times) I get

```
New York -> ALBANY -> Legal & Financial -> Legal -> ATTORNEYS 
New York -> ALBANY -> Legal & Financial -> Legal -> ATTORNEYS 
New York -> ALBANY -> Legal & Financial -> Legal -> ATTORNEYS 
New York -> ALBANY -> Legal & Financial -> Legal -> ATTORNEYS
New York -> ALBANY -> Legal & Financial -> Legal
New York -> ALBANY -> Legal & Financial
```

you may need to add a `trim` function here & there if you want to remove leading/trailing blanks.

Hope that helps

good luck

Answer (score 0):

MikeD's VBA solution is a very nice one.

For the record, here is a formula solution (thanks to [this thread](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=27041))

Put this formula to find the n-th occurence of a string in a new column:

```
=IF(LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,E1,""))>=F1*LEN(E1), SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE(B1,E1,"@",F1)),"Not Found")
```

where `B1` houses a target string, `E1` the character you are looking for ("->" in your case) and `F1` the n-th occurrence (5 in your case).

Afterwards, put this formula in another column:

```
=IF(B6<>"Not Found",MID(B1,1,B6-LEN(E1)),B6)
```

where `B6` is the result of the previous formula.

Comment: you want to get the # of occurences of the sep string in B1 by replacing sep string against a null string (clever !!). The delta will be F1 for a sep string of length `ls= 1`, and `ls*F1` for a sep string of length ls. Should you therefore not compare the `LEN(...)-LEN(...)` against `F1*LEN(E1)` ?

Comment: Damn! Thanks for pointing that out. I missed that part (of course, in the example of the thread, `LEN(E1)` was equal to 1 so they had to problem. I've edited my answer to reflect the change (and I would give you a +1 if I could for that comment :))

Comment: Thanks the VBA worked well. SOmeone mentioned that a pivot table could have also done the trick.. thoughts?

Comment: @DanielLeubitz: I don't think that would work because the pivot table wouldn't *split* the data. Btw, if the VBA answer fits your needs, you can accept it by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask